# Accessing Meteor application as another user

Tags: authentication, meteor

I've recently updated some parts of the code and want to check if they play well with production database, which has different data sets for different users. But I can only access the application as my own user.

How to see the Meteor application through the eyes of another user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: The best way to do this is to use a method

**Server side**

```
Meteor.methods({
    logmein: function(user_id_to_log_in_as) {
        this.setUserId(user_id_to_log_in_as);
    }
}):
```

**Client side**

```
Meteor.call("logmein", "<some user_id of who you want to be>");
```

This is kept simple for sake of clarity, feel free to place in your own security measures.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore since Meteor uses hashedTokens in `services.resume.loginToken`; this is on Meteor 1.1 but the change may have occurred earlier.

Comment: @Han yes you're right. I've updated the answer with the method that works best

Comment: Call `Meteor.connection.setUserId(userId)` in the client console as well.

Comment: Note: if you refresh the page or manually change the URL then your user will revert to the original one logged in. (This took me a bit of time to see what was happening).

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a [blog post](http://fogofcode.wordpress.com/2013/07/11/accessing-meteor-application-as-another-user/) about it. But here are the details:

On the server. Add a method that **only an admin** can call that would change the currently logged user programatically:

```
Meteor.methods(
  "switchUser": (username) ->
    user = Meteor.users.findOne("username": username)
    if user
      idUser = user["_id"]
      this.setUserId(idUser)
      return idUser
)
```

On the client. Call this method with the desired username and override the user on the client as well:

```
Meteor.call("switchUser", "usernameNew", function(idUser) {
    Meteor.userId = function() { return idUser;};
});
```

Refresh client to undo.

This may not be a very elegant solution but it does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly updated answer from the accepted to log the client in as new user as well as on the server.

```
logmein: function(user_id_to_log_in_as) {
  if (Meteor.isServer) {
    this.setUserId(user_id_to_log_in_as);
  }
  if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.connection.setUserId(user_id_to_log_in_as);
  }
},
```

More info here: http://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html#DDPCommon-MethodInvocation-setUserId